# Finding the elements of this subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find **all of the elements of the subgroup of C* generated by (1+*i*)/Sqrt[2]**.

---

I know how to find elements in a subgroup in Z and U, but I don't know where to start here.

Comment: Why don't you try computing $z, z^2, z^3, \ldots$, and seeing where that gets you.

Comment: So, can we say z=(1+i)/Sqrt(2), and then z^2 =(1/2)(1 + i)^2 = 0?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 +2i - 1) = i$. You should keep going (you could compute $z, z^2, z^4, z^8$ to speed things up).

Comment: $\mathbf{C}$ is an integral domain, so $z^2 = 0$ if and only if $z = 0$.

Comment: So this means z^2 would be i, and z^4 would be -1, and z^8 would be 1.  When would you stop this process?  When it reaches 1?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$z=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)=e^{\frac{\pi i}4+2k\pi i}\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies z^4=1$$

and now solve your quest.